# Angular HTTP API handling

Tags: angular, observable

I have some questions regarding Angular HTTP and Back end API 
1. I have an API which returns response like

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
    ],
    "message": ""
}
```

and Angular service handles HTTP as Observable which is streams of data but it doesn't look like stream.

2.If I want strongly typed,how can i do that?

is this correct method to take as  and mapped this as strongly typed by using

```
 .pipe(
       map((data: DataType[]) => {
         return data;
       })
```

Comment: Can you rephrase 1) as a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the generic version of the http api call (like get) you can include the type members (or define an interface and use that). Then you have type safety from that point on.

```
someServiceCall: Observable<Array<any>> {
  return this.httpClient.get<{"success":boolean; "data":Array<any>; "message":string}>('/some/api/end/point')
         .pipe(map(response) => response.data);
}
```

Additionally

- You should also replace the user of `any` with the appropriate type
- In your code the `map` handler has an array of `DataType` instances but your json is not an array it is an object that *contains* an array as one of the fields.
- Not sure if you have source control of the api end point but if you do: Do not include the success/failure as a part of the returned data. Instead use the appropriate status codes. If the API is successful then the return status will be 200 (or in the 200 to 299 range depending on the result type). If there was an error return an http status code (like 400 or 404 or 401 or 500 etc) and additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. In most cases the observables returned will complete after providing you with a value (the response). They can be piped to the `last` operator or in async methods it's convenient to use the `.toPromise()` on them.
2. Strongly typed:

The http methods themselves are generic, so you can do something like:

```
this.http.get<MyClass>(url);
```

Bonus tip: they are cold observables, meaning that they will not actually perform the request until there is a subscriber. So something like this:

```
this.http.post(url,data);
```

Won't do anything!